# How to create a link inside text in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

I have a cycle, in this cycle I print company description as a text.

```
<ul class="companies" th:each="company: ${companies}">
<li style="text-decoration:none"><strong th:text="${company.code}">Text1</strong> – <span th:text="${company.description}">description</span></li>
</ul>
```

but thing is, that I have inside "company.description" long text with one link. But in result link becomes just a text. How to create a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then `company.description` contains text with inside it a `<a href="...">` part. If you use `th:text`, then Thymeleaf will escape the HTML for safety reasons.

If you are absolutely sure this is not user data, you can use `th:utext`. But if this is data coming from an untrusted source (e.g. the users of your application), then this is a security risk as people can put in all kinds of HTML (or JavaScript!) code in there.

Comment: thank you, worked! btw, got useful information from your site (or blog), so thanks again)